# How to register eureka client from Grails on eureka server in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, grails, netflix-eureka, grails-2.4

I want to register my eureka client that is in Grails 2.4.4 on a eureka server which is in spring boot.

I already have registered another eureka service from spring boot on the same eureka server and it is working fine. 
When I run grails app, it gives me an error :

```
| Error 2018-02-21 17:29:39,765 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR aws.ConfigClusterResolver  - Cannot resolve to any endpoints from provided configuration: {defaultZone=[]}
| Error 2018-02-21 17:29:39,771 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR transport.EurekaHttpClients  - Initial resolution of Eureka server endpoints failed. Check ConfigClusterResolver logs for more info
| Error 2018-02-21 17:29:39,841 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR discovery.DiscoveryClient  - DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/pawan - was unable to refresh its cache! status = There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty
Message: There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty
    Line | Method
->>  107 | execute                          in com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    134 | getApplications                  in com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator
|    137 | execute . . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6
|     77 | execute                          in com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient
|    134 | getApplications . . . . . . . .  in com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator
|   1051 | getAndStoreFullRegistry          in com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient
|    965 | fetchRegistry . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    414 | <init>                           in     ''
|    269 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    265 | <init>                           in     ''
|    257 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     31 | initializeEurekaClient           in EurekaConfiguration
|     20 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in BootStrap$_closure1
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1149 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
```

Here is my application.properties file:

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Grails Metadata file

#Grails Metadata file
#Grails Metadata file
#Fri Jan 19 17:25:36 IST 2018
app.grails.version=2.4.4
app.name=GrailsMicroservice
app.version=0.1
#app.port=8080
eureka.region = default
eureka.vipAddress = localhost
eureka.port = 1116eureka.name=Grails-Service
eureka.hostname=localhost
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:1116/eureka/
```

Any help will be appriciable.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my findings that I have applied to this issue. However, I did lots of search on google to get it right back on the track.

**Step 1:** Create a file named `eureka-client.properties`

**Step 2:** Now remove your configuration code from `application.properties` file and paste it into the newly created file.

**Step 3:** Pass your eureka port there and of course `serviceId` in this file.

**Configuration CODE:**

```
app.grails.version=2.4.4
app.name=GrailsMicroservice
app.version=0.1
#app.port=8080
eureka.region = default
eureka.vipAddress = localhost
eureka.port = 1116
eureka.name=Grails-Service
eureka.hostname=localhost
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:1116/eureka/
```

Now save the changes and run your application. It will connect to your Eureka server. After refreshing your Eureka home page, you will find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a TYPO in your question or a genuine error but the line `eureka.port = 1116eureka.name=Grails-Service` should be:

```
eureka.port = 1116
eureka.name=Grails-Service
```

Comment: It's like in the same way is the properties file.